# tengo un problema con este ejercicio en java

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

el problema es el siguiente:
 Cree una clase llamada MisMetodos, la cual debe contener 2 métodos, uno de tipo void y otro que retorne valor, este último debe tener un parámetro. El primer método debe imprimir el mensaje “Hola Feliz día” y el segundo método debe enviársele como argumento el mensaje “Muchas gracias igualmente”. Debe invocar cada método desde la clase que tiene el método Main.

yo he desarrollado un poco pero ya no entendi
solo hice esto:
la verdad no se si es haci

```
public void mensaje1()
{
   System.out.println("hola feli dia");

   public String mensaje2(String cadena)
   {
     return cadena;
   }

}

class demomimetodo{

public static main(String args 
public static void main (String agrs[]) 

}
```

Comment: A ver, cual es la parte que no entiendes?

Comment: No puedes meter un método dentro de otro método, tienen que ser dos distintos, necesitas un objeto para ejecutar un méotodo o hacerlo estático, y por último java y javascript son dos lenguajes totalmente distintos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta/duda no es bien clara, pero, tratare de ayudarte.

Si entendi bien tu situacion, el codigo seria el siguiente:

class Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Hago una instancia de la clase "MisMetodos"
        MisMetodos instancia = new MisMetodos();
        
        // Llamo al "metodo1" para que imprima el mensaje "Hola Feliz Dia"
        instancia.metodo1();
        
        // Llamo al "metodo2" enviandole un mensaje como argumento para que lo imprima
        instancia.metodo2("Muchas gracias igualmente");
    }

}
```

public class MisMetodos:

```
public class MisMetodos {
    
    // "metodo1" tipo void, no recibe parametros
    public void metodo1() {
        System.out.println("Hola Feliz Dia");
    }
    
    // "metodo2" tipo void, recibe un String como parametro
    public void metodo2(String parametro) {
        System.out.println(parametro);
    }

}
```

La salida de este codigo es:

> Hola Feliz Dia
>
> Muchas gracias igualmente

Espero haberte ayudado con tu problema, si es el caso, no olvides seleccionar mi comentario como la Respuesta Aceptada.

Saludos.

Comment: gracias amigo .